# App created in Xcode 9 crashes with screen record on in iPhone iOS11

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I created a couple of apps and side loaded them on my iPhone.

I was playing around with my iPhone screen recorder and noticed the apps I side loaded, would close out.

Apps like LinkedIn, Twitter, shopping apps will stay on top.

Is there a setting in Xcode that prevents this?

Comment: Without showing the actual code causing the crash it is quite hard to help you. Please include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Add a symbolicated crash log and the relevant portion of your code indicating the line the code crashed at.

Comment: It is not the code. After further search among the internet and Apple website, it is because I have the free personal account and the app will only work for a few days. I even tried to archive the app and load it to my phone via Apple Configurator 2 and it still only works for a few days.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer. I had updated to iOS 11.0.1, thats when the crash started. Worked well with iOS 11. Just reloaded the app from Xcode and it works now. At this writing, the Apple Developer website is down for maintenance, so I am unable to load my other apps.